# Click create two separate arrays?

Tags: angular

I have customer.html:

```
   <app-z-grid title="Tip korisnika" [restPath]="'customertype'" (fillDetailParent)="reinit($event)"></app-z-grid>

   <app-z-grid title="Podtip korisnika" [path]='"customerclassification/customerstype.json"' [restPath]="'customerstype'" [isDetail]="'customerstype'" [parentName]="'customertypeCode'" ></app-z-grid>
```

In my app-z-grid component i have this:

```
  pinTab(event: any) {
        this.pinned=!this.pinned;
        if (this.pinned) {
            this.pinnedTabs.push(this.title);
            console.log('if stat',this.pinnedTabs);
        }
        else {
            this.pinnedTabs.splice(this.pinnedTabs.indexOf(this.title), 1);
            console.log('else state',this.pinnedTabs);
        }
```

in app-z-grid.html i have button like this:

```
  <button (click) ="pinTab(title)" class="btn btn-block-container mousePointer">
      <i class="fa fa-thumb-tack" [hidden]="!pinned" style="color:white!important;"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-thumb-tack fa-rotate-90" [hidden]="pinned" style="color:white!important;"></i>
  </button>
```

Now when i click on first pin it push it into array, but when i click on other pin it push it in other array. Any suggestion why is that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components do not share state. Each component (`<app-z-grid>`) has it's own state and instance of the backing "controller/Class". If you want to share the `pinnedTabs` array between components you'll have to look at the component interaction cookbook by angular team: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: i dont want to share i want when user click on  app-z-grid to add title in same array for both components , and not to create separate

Comment: so you want to share the **same** array between both instances of component right?

Comment: so my answer still stands. You need to share the array with both instances by a service and via parent component as the link I posted above suggests. good luck